# Can I add bold or italic text in the Luna theme on Big Cartel?

Tags: css, product, bigcartel

I'm trying to add bold and italic headings to my product listing text, however this does not appear to be an option. It's an option on the 'pages' I create for my website, so I feel like I'm missing something obvious! I'm currently using the Big Cartel Luna theme but happy to switch to something else if this is the fix! I saw a code online that I entered into the CSS section however there was no change. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: can you provide full of code or example result